# mysqldump tab into tar.gz

Tags: mysql

I'd like to use mysqldump with the -T function and somehow compress it in one step, to save writing the uncompressed files to disk (it's a really big database).

```
mysqldump -T/directory databasename
```

This would just write all the files to /directory, but I'd like to send it directly into a .tar.gz archive.  Any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't possible. using the -T option causes the mysqld server process (not the mysqldump process) to write to the specified directory. therefore, there's no stream to redirect through tar and gzip.

any particular reason you need tab delimited files?

Comment: We're using them for possible import into another type of database later on.

Comment: ok then, not possible. you'll either have to come up with a completely different solution, or live with compressing the files after the fact.